# Permission denied on Github despite working keys

Tags: git, github

There are plenty of questions and discussions about denied permissions when pushing on GitHub. Most of them were caused by incorrect or missing keys. In my case I can successfully connect to GitHub via:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\daniel/.ssh/id_rsa':
Hi daniel! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But when I clone my repo using `git://` and push some changes I receive:

```
$ git clone ...
...
$ git pull
Already up to date. <--- !!! This works
...
$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa':
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://github.com/rickroll/Example.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).: exit status 255
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:rickroll/Example.git
```

I verified the entry in my config that matches my username + projectname that I can access:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:rickroll/example.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: See if this works `git config lfs.locksverify false`

Comment: The error message for LFS disappears but still no success. Same error

Comment: Is your ssh agent running? If not, run your ssh agent using `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` . Then try  to push.

Comment: Odd, using `GitHub Desktop` with the same prompt worked :-(

Comment: Yes, it's running